# Error while converting MS SQL query to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a project in C# where i have to convert the MS SQL Queries to MySQL Queries in my Data Access Layer Files. After Conversion I have encountered "Fatal error encountered during command execution." Error. Following is my MySQL Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mst_tariff 
WHERE  service_id = @service_id     
AND ( effective_from BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(@EFFECTIVE_FROM,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') 
AND STR_TO_DATE(@EFFECTIVE_TO,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')              
OR effective_to BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(@EFFECTIVE_FROM,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') 
AND STR_TO_DATE(@EFFECTIVE_TO,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')      
OR STR_TO_DATE(@EFFECTIVE_FROM,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') BETWEEN effective_from AND  
effective_to )      
AND is_active = 'y'   
AND tariff_id != @tariff_id
```

And following is my MS SQL query

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mst_tariff 
WHERE  service_id = @service_id     
AND ( effective_from BETWEEN convert(datetime,@EFFECTIVE_FROM,103) AND convert  
(datetime,@EFFECTIVE_TO,103)              
OR effective_to BETWEEN convert(datetime,@EFFECTIVE_FROM,103) AND convert  
(datetime,@EFFECTIVE_TO,103)      
OR convert(datetime,@EFFECTIVE_FROM,103) BETWEEN convert(datetime,effective_from,103) AND convert
(datetime,effective_to,103) )      
AND is_active = 'y'   
AND tariff_id != @tariff_id
```

Here effective_from and effective_to are date columns.

I am fairly new at this. So can anyone please verify whether the query is rite or not,whether the conversion from MS Sql to MySQL is correct or not.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What're EFFECTIVE_TO, EFFECTIVE_FROM, tariff_id, etc? where and how are defined?

Comment: And what is this error exactly? "Fatal error encountered during command execution." says nothing really. Can't you directly execute MySQL query in console/phpmyadmin/whatever client you have and show exact error from server?

Comment: @piotrekkr Yes sir. I have tried executing the statement directly in MySQL and it works there.But while running my project, I tried to debug the code. And this is the error that shows up on exception. Since the error said that error occured during command execution.i thought the issue might be with the query itself.Also have checked other websites for solution. Some say that the query is complex and it is taking much time to execute so sometimes it crosses the default time out and returning fatal error.

Comment: Do you have some limits for query execution time? Do you have error log with more detailed information about this error?